# Access object values in array nested in JSON object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a GET request that sends back a JSON object structured like this:

```
{"ID":5176,
"DateFrom":"8/29/2018",
"DateTo":"8/29/2018",
"Units":[{"Key":"Value","Key2": "Value2"}]
}
```

I cannot access Units[0] value.  I have tried the following:

```
testFunction(){
this.service.getJSON(params)
.subscribe((data) => { 
  this.model = data;
  this.dateFrom = this.model.DateFrom;
  this.dateTo = this.model.DateTo;
  this.unit = this.model.Units.Key;
  console.log(this.unit); //undefined
  }); 
 }
}
ngOnInit() {
this.testFunction();

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: ```this.unit = this.model.Units[0].Key;```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). `data` is an object, no JSON involved in the "problem".

Comment: this.unit = this.model.Units[0];  and this.unit.key return your value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
this.unit = this.model.Units[0].Key;
```

instead of

```
this.unit = this.model.Units.Key;
```

since `Units.Key` is undefined

Comment: I tried that and now receive this error:

"Unable to get property 'Key' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: are you sure you are receiving the json from your service? try console.log(this.model) to confirm .

Comment: I am sure its coming back as my date properties are able to be bound on my view

Comment: This is 100% correct...I foolishly thought I was specifying the index on Key and using 'this.model.Units[1].Key' and it returned undefined because well...a 2nd object didn't exist -_-.  Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the answer so it will help some else as well

Answer (score 0):

Since Units is an array of JSONs and the array contains only one element.
It should be accessed by Units[0].

Units[0] is now a JSON, Key property is needed now.
There are 2 ways to access it

1. Units[0].Key
2. Units[0]['Key']

The final code should look like

```js
testFunction(){
this.service.getJSON(params)
.subscribe((data) => { 
  this.model = data;
  this.dateFrom = this.model.DateFrom;
  this.dateTo = this.model.DateTo;
  //first method
  //this.unit = this.model.Units[0].Key;
  // second method
  // this.unit = this.model.Units[0]['Key'];

  console.log(this.unit); //undefined
  }); 
 }
}
ngOnInit() {
this.testFunction();

}
```